# How to draw rectangles consecutively in sth like a loop in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, drawing, rectangles

I need to draw rectangles in a Winform something like this image:

[image]

I also should be more clear. I want to achieve this scenario: Let's say there is a text in form like "ABCDEFG" When user clicks the B letter I want to add a background rectangle with color (highlight) to that letter and the successive 3 letters (in this case, I want to highlight BCD).

In a method i tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    letterArea = new Rectangle(rectStartX, rectStartY, (int)Math.Ceiling(charSize.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(charSize.Height));
    rectStartX += (int)Math.Ceiling(charSize.Width);
}
```

I call Invalidate() at the end of this method. In the OnPaintBackGround i have these lines:

```
Rectangle rectContent = vsr.GetBackgroundContentRectangle(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), letterArea);
```

where letterArea is a class field. I read in another question that calling Invalidate() in a loop doesn't guarantee the calling of OnPaintBackground. I am not interested in calculating coordinates, instead, i am interested in which method I must draw rectangles and where to call Invalidate() and what is the efficient solution?
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: *Invalidate* sends a paint message to the window. Paint sends respectively an *erasebackground*. Sending one or 1000 invalidates within a loop doesn't change anything. Only one paint message will be send in the end. It is common practice to draw in *paint*

Comment: _calling Invalidate() in a loop doesn't guarantee the calling of OnPaintBackground._ Yes it does. Maybe not immediately and not more often than necessary, but you can safely rely on the control to be derdrawn.

Comment: In your method you create several Rectangles but you don't do anything with them? If you add them to a class level List<Rectangle> your paint event could use it to fill each of them..

Comment: Will this efficient or is it the correct way to solve the problem? or just a solution?

Comment: This will be fine. No reason to even think about efficiency at this level.. Is it the best way? No idea because, frankly you didn't desribe the problem well. You show us a nice image but it doesn't have any letters, so how does it relate??

Answer (score 0):

You should draw your rectangles in [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method rather that in `OnPaintBackground`.

Also note that calling `Invalidate()` doesn't not force a synchronous paint. To force a synchronous paint, call `Update()` after calling the `Invalidate()` or use `Refresh()` which is doing the same as Invalidate + Update (but affects child controls too). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Comment: Andy I updated my question to be more clear. Is drawing in OnPaint still true when I want to highlight the background of some letters? Thanks.

Comment: In Forms code, you _always_ want to draw in `OnPaint()`. You need to maintain data structures that describe your visual appearance (e.g. a list of rectangles, highlighting of text, etc.), call `Invalidate()` when any of that data changes, and then draw the correct visual appearance when `OnPaint()` is called. Also note that while .NET provides a synchronous paint API, it's almost never the right thing to use it. Waiting for the WM_PAINT message (which is what causes `OnPaint()` to be called) and redrawing then is the normal and correct approach.